# openapi-generator-cli typescript-axios get only response.data

Tags: openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator-cli typescript-axios for generating client from swagger and generated clients functions returns full request data(header, config, url, etc) but i want only response.data(data that real function returns).

I do not want to wrap client's functions in a new function like wrapperFunction(response => response.data).

Is there any config or anything different to get only response.data?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood the question.
You can get a portion of object like this

```
const {data} = axios.get(url)
```

This way you can retrieve data value of object returned by "axios" request.

You can change name of variable

```
const {data: myVarName} = axios.get(url)
```